# How to change ArcGIS map service export map operation format to jpeg by default

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a map service which is by default exporting map in png format.

I am aware of using the ArcGIS JavaScript API to change the format by changing the request from the client side from png to jpeg.

However is it possible to make the changes to the service itself, can we force the map service to send the export map operation in jpeg format by default?

I have checked all the options in the ArcGIS admins rest, manager and the options before publishing the map in ArcMap. However, there implement the default format for export map operation.

Any help would be appreciated!